# Find stereo isomers of camphor

Tags: stereochemistry

The compound given is camphor:

[image: 1,7,7-trimethylbicyclo[2.2.1]heptan-2-one]

We have to find the total number of stereoisomers for this compound. Now I can see two chiral carbons so I thought the number would be $4$ but it turns out that there are only $2$.

I can't quite see why. I realize that it is a bridgehead compound which would make it non-planar but how does that affect stereochemistry? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The bridgehead atoms have to be inverted simultaneously. You can't have a hydrogen or methyl group pointing inside. Technically, we should ask how many stereoisomers are reasonable.

Comment: To follow-up on @Zhe's answer, the enantiomer arises by inverting both stereoisomers. However, you are correct conceptually. Inverting only one stereocenter at a time gives a pair of "trans" enantiomers that are too unstable to exist.